# Slicing divs in CSS

Tags: css

I was just wondering if it was possible to, say, slice a div so from either side.

For example, say I have a div "box"

```
#box {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

and I wanted to slice a piece from the left with width of 20px and height of 100px, and instead make it transparent, but everything is still where it was before the slice.

I researched and all I could find was how to create transparent border corners.

Is there anyway a div can be sliced or allow a specific area of the div to be transparent?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

[image]

This is what I am trying to do, I want to make the ~50px on the left of the second div with the form transparent so it looks like it's behind the first div. I know some may suggest I use z-index but it won't work.

Comment: Nope, that would make no sense. `div` are _dividers_ or 'slices' by themselves.

Comment: It sounds impossible, but maybe you should add an image of what you're trying to do.

Comment: and what's wrong with a right transparent border?

Comment: It's a border and adds to the div, I want something that already exists to be transparent. @Itay I will create an image, give me a minute :)

Comment: Why is something like `z-index` not possible in your example? It looks like the _perfect_ use case for z-index.

Comment: can you replicate this with a demo (jsfiddle/jsbin etc) /show us the site so that we can tinker with it?

Comment: `z-index` requires some form of `position` in the css. (example `position: relative`)

Comment: The modal is -100000 z-index and it's still infront of the left div

Comment: Now I fixed it a bit, at `z-index = -20` it appears behind the left div but instantly disappears. Why does this happen, I couldn't find an answer on google except for bootstrap answers, but this isn't bootstrap.

Comment: @somethinghere I'm so sorry for the spam, but I got z-index working, unfortunately, It is un-clickable, and it needs to be `position: fixed;`, how do I make it clickable? Please write an answer so I can check it and give you credit :)

Comment: @SamirChahine I have posted an example, but without more precise code it will be hard to say what exactly is going on there - you probably have a lot of CSS working hand in hand there. Try to right click and inspect the element, and see if that selects the box you were expecting. If not, another - maybe invisible? - box might be overlapping it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the perfect use case for `z-index`, a property that requires positioning other than static but otherwise works as expected, changing the layer order of your items. I am not sure what the issue is you are encountering (something not clickable is always possible if another invisible element is overlaying it - the best way to find out is to right click and inspect element to see if the right element get selected).

I have added a little snippet that shows you how z-index is supposed and can work. I keep increasing the z-index, which is obviously a bad idea and it would be better to sort them, but for the purpose of this example it does fine.

The best tip I can give, however, is to try to use as many *positive* z-indexes as possible. Negative z-index can sink under things such as your body and its pseudo elements, making it hard to figure out what is going on. I also believe that when we are talking in positive numbers it makes a lot more sense to our puny human brains!

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
var index = 4;

for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) divs[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.style.zIndex = ++index;
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
div + div {
  z-index: 0;
  left: 120px;
  top: 120px;
  background: red;
}
div + div + div {
  z-index: 1;
  left: 140px;
  top: 140px;
  background: blue;
}
div + div + div + div {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 160px;
  top: 160px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>-1</div>
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
```

As for documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Let me know if this helps, as I am, obviously, unclear what precise issues you are seeing.

Comment: @SamirChahine Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linear-gradients` and `after` `pseudo-element` to achieve this

i used `linear-gradient` to make the div half transparent and placed an `after` `pseudo-element` to hide half of the transparent part

```css
body{
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/500/500');
    background-size:cover;
}
div{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:2px solid;
    background:linear-gradient(transparent 50%,orange 50%);
    position:relative;
}

div:after{
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    z-index:-1;
    background:orange;
    left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That is _so_ odd. It might be because it's Friday, but I can't wrap my brain around this one. Cool though, I didn't know this was possible. +1

Comment: @somethinghere It is actually quite simple linear gradient produces a half filled square and then just put an `after` having half width on the right side :)

Comment: When you say it like that is seems simple, yes :) Cool, learn something new every day!

Comment: Glad i could help  @somethinghere